# Find k $\frac{1}{(3a-b)^2}+\frac{1}{(3b-c)^2}+\frac{1}{(3c-a)^2} \ge \frac{k}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

Tags: inequality

Find k with
$$\frac{1}{(3a-b)^2}+\frac{1}{(3b-c)^2}+\frac{1}{(3c-a)^2} \ge \frac{k}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$

Comment: $k=-1$ will do for values where the left hand side and right hand side are both defined - or did you mean something different.

Comment: It seems likely that he's asking for the best possible $k$.

Comment: @Mark Bennet find all k, not just one

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want to minimize $$f(a,b,c) = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)\left(\frac{1}{(3a-b)^2} + \frac{1}{(3b-c)^2} + \frac{1}{(3c-a)^2}\right)$$
(presumably for $a,b,c$ real numbers).
By homogeneity, we may restrict to the sphere $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$.
Using a Lagrange multiplier, we look for critical points of $F(a,b,c,\lambda) = f(a,b,c) + \lambda (a^2 + b^2 + c^2-1)$.  The solution is rather unpleasant.  It seems the minimum is approximately $0.808645463814078870$.

EDIT: In fact this number turns out to be the real root of the polynomial
$$2460640\,{z}^{3}-2787824\,{z}^{2}+905866\,z-210681$$

Comment: why do we need Lagrange multiplier, there're  no constraints?

Comment: Without the restriction, you get critical rays rather than a finite number of critical points.